# Percentage of white pixel

Tags: matlab

After performing processing I want to calculate the percentage of white pixels between this images after the change.

I'm doing this: var = (int2str(nnz(Img2)) / int2str(nnz(Img1))) * 100;

but it returns as result ]

What's the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [INT2STR](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/int2str.html) is only needed to convert an integer value to a string (usually for the purpose of displaying it). If you just want the numerical value, leave that out:

```
var = 100*nnz(Img2)/nnz(Img1);
```

If you now want to turn `var` into a string value, you can use [NUM2STR](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/num2str.html) (since `var` is likely not going to be an integer value any more):

```
varString = num2str(var);
```

Comment: It's giving me: Warning: Out of range or non-integer values truncated during conversionto character.

When I use it in this case : 

title(['Percentage : ' 100 * nnz(Img4) / nnz(image) ]);

Comment: @AZIRAR: First, you need to do `num2str(100 * nnz(Img4) / nnz(image))` to convert the number to a string. Second, I would avoid using `image` as a variable name, since there is already a built-in function called IMAGE.